# Is there a way to get host Hyper-V UUID from linux gest?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, centos, hyper-v, uuid

I have a CentOS 6.4 runing on Hyper-V VM. If I export the VM to other Hyper-V server, the UUID keeps the same. Is there a way to avoid this, or use other identifyer to know that the host hardware have changed?

Thanks, and hope posting on right StackExchange site.